# Joining on 2 tables but only selecting rows from one of the tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables with identical names and schema. I would like to join on them, but only select  rows from one of the tables. What is a good way to do this? The below query selects the rows from both tables, but I just want table a2 from the other DB.

```
select a.fkey_id, a2.fkeyid_id, a.otherthing, a2.otherthing from mytable a 
    inner join otherdb.dbo.mytable a2 on a.fkey_id=a2.fkey_id
```

I tried using left outer join but since the schemas are identical between the 2 tables this doesn't seem to work. 
EDIT: I am only including the "a" table columns in the select to get an idea of what values the rows are returning. I just don't want any rows returned from "a", so I'd like to filter those rows out somehow.

Comment: So, modify your `Select` statement to only include the fields you care about...?

Comment: just leave out `a.fkey_id` and `a.otherthing`

Comment: Uh, don't reference `a.anything` in the select list

Comment: If you don't want to list all the columns, you can just SELECT a2.* from mytable a INNER JOIN otherdb.dbo.mytable a2 ...

Comment: @pmbAustin Or don't use SELECT * and just list the columns needed (that table could have 400 columns for all you know).

Comment: You can't filter out rows from an inner join - either both tables are included, or both tables aren't. You can only filter out which columns you show from those matching rows. Or you can use `EXISTS` like M.Ali's answer - this will only return the data from one table regardless of how you express the column list.

Comment: your edit makes even less sense than the original question. just avoid your `a` table in the `SELECT`. problem solved

Answer (score 3):

Just take out the references to "a2" columns from the select list.

```
select a.fkey_id, a.otherthing from mytable a 
    inner join otherdb.dbo.mytable a2 on a.fkey_id=a2.fkey_id
```

OR

```
select a.* from mytable a 
    inner join otherdb.dbo.mytable a2 on a.fkey_id=a2.fkey_id
```

Which begs the questions on why you're joining to the other table if you don't want data from it. Is this a filtering method? If so, it would better performance-wise to do an exists.

```
select a.* from mytable a 
 WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM otherdb.dbo.mytable a2 
      WHERE a.fkey_id=a2.fkey_id)
```

Comment: Why *? We know exactly which two columns the OP is after.

Comment: Did you see my first example?

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.fkey_id
     , a.otherthing
from mytable a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM  otherdb.dbo.mytable a2
              WHERE a.fkey_id=a2.fkey_id)
```